# crontab does not run properly

Tags: shell, cron-task

Somehow my crontab script does not run like it should

```
* * * * 1,3,5 cd /home/username/test/ && /usr/bin/ping -c 1 example.com &> /dev/null && (XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) /usr/bin/notify-send "Updating Data" && /usr/bin/npx cypress run) || XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) /usr/bin/notify-send "Data update failed"
```

It should go to the /home/username/test/ directory, then ping a server and based on if it get a response or not (notify-send AND run a run a cypress script) OR notify-send.
But somehow decides to send both notifications and ignore the script.
Why does this happen and how do i fix it?
If i run it in the commandline without the timesettings it works.

Comment: You could put all this in a script (and modify as required) and call the script.  Easier to debug as well than a llllooonnnggg single line command.

Comment: `&>/dev/null` is a bashism. A crontab runs with `/bin/sh` by default. Use `>/dev/null 2>&1` instead.

Comment: Anyhow -- this is more a [unix.se] question as currently written, being more about the cron daemon than about software development as such.

Comment: The other thing is that `a && b || c` **is not** `if a; then b; else c; fi`, and trying to pretend that it is gets you into messes like this one. Don't chain short-circuiting booleans unless you've thought about the corner cases (To be specific: if `a` succeeds and `b` fails, then you get `c` invoked even though `a`'s exit status was successful; and using bash-only syntax in a sh script is an easy way to get a failure... or to have an `&` in `&>` interpreted as "put the thing on the left in the background").